# Tmux: How to configure tmux to display the current working directory of a pane on the status bar?

Tags: configuration, tmux

I am new to tmux and I am trying to edit my tmux.conf file to have the left side of the status bar reflect:

`[SessionName] [CurrentPane] [CurrentWorkingDirectory]`

I am able to display the `SessionName` and `CurrentPane`. However I can't get to display the `CurrentWorkingDirectory`.

I've tried several `#(shell command)` options:

1. `#(tmux select-pane -t :.#P; pwd)` :
       But this prints some other $PWD variable which does **NOT** reflect
       the current directory of the bash session in the current pane.
2. `#(tmux select-pane -t :.#P; tmux send-keys pwd Enter)`
            Firstly, although it did print the `CurrentWorkingDirectory` if I'm
           in a terminal. It prints this in the terminal and **NOT** in the status
           bar like how I want it.  Secondly, It entered "pwd Enter" every 15
           seconds whether or not I was in a terminal, which was a hassle to
           reverse if your not as quick (like I am).

I've tried these options but to no avail, is it possible to do what I want? and how?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is a variable for that, which doesn't seem to be in the manpage but is mentioned in the development version. For me, it works in the 1.8 release of tmux.

```
set -g status-left "#{pane_current_path}"
```

Note that it also works when you put it in the window-status. Each window status will mention respective working directories.

```
setw -g window-status-format "#{pane_current_path}".
```

Comment: This renames the pane only when a new pane is made for me

Comment: My status bar was too short so it was truncating the path. Use `set -g status-left-length 85` to increase the length

Comment: Works for tmux 2.1:

```set-option -g status-right '#{pane_current_path}'```

Also to increase interval of updating current dir at status I use setting:
```set-option -g status-interval 1```

Comment: @WillHardwick-Smith is it only when a new pane is made?  I thought that at first, but after some experimenting realized it was only when I SWITCHED panes.  Then I realized this was a good thing!  For panes in the foreground it will show the running command, for panes in the background it will show the directory

Comment: For the current window, it's "window-status-current-format", and for every other window, it's "window-status-format", at least in tmux 3.1. 
I also use b:pane_current_path to only have the basename and not the whole path

Comment: And how to display it (dynamically) on the pane-border (not the status-bar) as a pane title?

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure how to do this in bash, but in zsh, there's a hook that gets run before every command. In your .zshrc:

```
precmd () {
    tmux set -qg status-left "#S #P $(pwd)"
}
```

This will run that `tmux` command everytime you run a command. Hope this helps. Since `bash` doesn't have a `precmd`, I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Because I'm novice to Linux and began learning in bash, I don't want to make the switch to zsh unless I really must. Hence the reason I prefer a solution for bash.

Comment: I did however found a way to make run precmd with bash using a trick by [Glyph Lefkowitz](http://glyf.livejournal.com/63106.html). 
A solution was found [here](http://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command). Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the proposed solution does not work for version 1.7 - "official version" for OpenSuse 12.3, but I managed to find a solution:
     In `/etc/tmux.conf`:

```
setw -g window-status-current-format "#T(#I:#W#F)"  
setw -g window-status-format "#T(#I:#W#F)"
```

Here #T - tells to display current pane title, which can be set with some escape sequence. For doing this at each shell command, put
somewhere in `.bashrc`:

```
[[ -n "$TMUX" ]] && PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -n -e "\e]2;${PWD/${HOME}/~}\e\\"'
```

This works  for me on OpenSuse 12.3, tmux 1.7, bash 4.2.53.

Comment: Yes, of course! The spaces are required after [[ and before ]]. I copied a line from the terminal window after the test and did not notice that the spaces that this spaces have disappeared  when displaying.