# How to make tmux get the current working directory from ipython?

Tags: bash, ipython, tmux

Bear with me for a sec while I explain the motivation for my question.

I've tmux set so that it shows the current working directory on the tmux status line. This works fine except in the following scenario:

While on a bash shell, I fire up ipython. On ipython, I change directory to some other place in my disk (doing 'cd some_place'). This works in the sense that I'm cd'ed to that directory, but the tmux status line still shows the original directory from which I fired ipython as the current working directory, instead of the one that I'm now.

I *know that this is no bug*, tmux is just showing me the original directory, all the "cd's" that I launch from ipython are transparent to that hosting shell.

My question is: Can you think of a way to make tmux get the current working directory from ipython instead of the original (hosting) shell from which it was launched?

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16659487/283649), you could manually update the status using a command like the one provided in the linked answer:

```
!tmux set -qg status-left "#S #P $(pwd)"
```

Includes the `!` for ipython shell calls. This is, however, a manual action. Maybe there is a way to run it automatically.